# How to perform clustering of a large number of nodes?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, graphs, clustering

I have a clustering problem with around 400-500 nodes. The edge between any two nodes has a weight (between 0 and 1, 0: can be considered as there is no edge/connection between these two nodes) as shown in the figure. I haven’t drawn all the edges so as not to make the figure messy. Generally, the edge between the nodes that are far away from each other has low weight.

I need to perform clustering of these nodes. Lets say we want to put the nodes in 7-8 clusters/groups.

The objective is that the sum-weight in each cluster should be maximized. This may also generate clusters where the number of edges connecting two clusters is low.[image]

Problem Statement:

Let $N=500$, $G=8$ and maximum cluster/group size is 70.

Let

binary decision variable $x_{i,g}$ indicate whether node $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ appears in group $g\in\{1,\dots,G\}$,

binary decision variable $y_{i,j,g}$ indicate whether edge $(i,j)$ appears in group $g$.

We want to maximize $$\sum_{i<j}\sum_g w_{i,j} y_{i,j,g}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_g x_{i,g} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1 \\
\sum_i x_{i,g} &\le 70 &&\text{for all $g$} \\
y_{i,j,g} &\le x_{i,g} &&\text{for all $i<j$ and all $g$} \\
y_{i,j,g} &\le x_{j,g} &&\text{for all $i<j$ and all $g$} \\
\end{align}

As we can see this a binary integer programming problem and has large number of optimization variable. Difficult to solve. Also I cannot afford a solver.

I prefer a less-complex solution.

Comment: Tried k-means with distance =$1\over W$?

Comment: @Sutanu in my case  this relation does not hold true for al the pairs. Also, k-means is kind of random, different runs give different clustering results!

Comment: Your first constraint is $\le$ rather than $=.$ Does that mean you are willing to leave some nodes not assigned to any cluster?

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/how-to-partition-a-graph-with-optimal-number-of-groups

Comment: For fast heuristics, search for "community detection"

Comment: @prubin sorry for my mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: @RobPratt do you have any good reference?

Comment: SAS, my employer, provides community detection routines, and the documentation lists two references: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_036/casmlnetwork/casmlnetwork_network_details67.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple hill-climbing approximate solver in Python which seems to work quite well:

```py
import numpy as np

def cluster(weights, n_groups, max_size):
    n = weights.shape[0]
    assert n_groups * max_size >= n
    group_weights = np.zeros((n, n_groups))
    groups = np.empty(n, dtype=int)
    group_sizes = np.zeros(n_groups, dtype=int)
    idxs = np.arange(n)
    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
    score = 0
    for i in idxs:
        g = i % n_groups
        groups[i] = g
        group_sizes[g] += 1
        score += group_weights[i,g]
        group_weights[:,g] += weights[i]
    while True:
        #Reassignment phase
        changed = False
        for i in idxs:
            g = groups[i]
            w = np.copy(group_weights[i])
            w[group_sizes == max_size] = -1
            h = np.argmax(w)
            ds = group_weights[i,h] - group_weights[i,g]
            if ds <= 1e-16:
                continue
            changed = True
            groups[i] = h
            group_sizes[g] -= 1
            group_sizes[h] += 1
            score += ds
            group_weights[:,g] -= weights[i]
            group_weights[:,h] += weights[i]
        #Swapping phase
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if j == i:
                    continue
                g = groups[i]
                h = groups[j]
                ds = (group_weights[i,h] - group_weights[i,g]) + (group_weights[j,g] - group_weights[j,h]) - 2 * weights[i,j]
                if ds <= 1e-16:
                    continue
                changed = True
                groups[i] = h
                groups[j] = g
                score += ds
                dw = weights[j] - weights[i]
                group_weights[:,g] += dw
                group_weights[:,h] -= dw
        if not changed:
            break
    return groups, score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.seed(0)

    N = 500
    max_size = 70
    n_groups = 8
    weights = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (N, N))
    weights = np.tril(weights, -1) + np.triu(weights.T, 1)

    groups, score = cluster(weights, n_groups, max_size)

    print(groups)
    print(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a genetic algorithm to the problem, although (a) I'm not sure it would be considered "less-complex" and (b) it definitely would have a random component, with different runs likely producing different clusters. You would want to use a GA library, but fortunately there are high-quality open-source libraries for most languages. I have a [demo](https://rubin.msu.domains/blog/ga_clustering.nb.html) coded as an R notebook (using the "GA" R library).

Answer (score 1):

This is the [graph partitioning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition). In your formulation, you are trying to maximize the weight of edges that are inside a cluster, instead of minimizing the weight of edges between clusters, but both are equivalent.

There are very good heuristics, some of which are explained on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition). And very good solvers based on these heuristics.

I suggest either [Metis](https://github.com/KarypisLab/METIS) or [Kahypar](https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar). Both are free software and have bindings for multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to maximize intra-cluster weight, firstly, subtract each edge weight from 1. On the resulting graph, solve a Minimum Spanning Tree (MST). If you would like 2 clusters, remove the costliest edge in the MST solution. If you would like 3 clusters, remove the costliest and next costliest edge in the MST solution...If you would like m clusters, remove the m-1 costliest edges in the MST solution. This is a heuristic and relatively easy to implement solution to your problem.

Comment: MST can be used for clustering, but it doesn't respect the cardinality constraints ($\le 70$ nodes per cluster).

Comment: @RobPratt Well, in the worst case, one could satisfy the cardinality constraint also by removing all edges -- you would end up with singleton clusters. So, in this case, (since it is anyway only a heuristic solution), the OP should keep removing edges up until the time when cardinality constraint is met.

Comment: The number of clusters is also required to be $8$.

Comment: @RobPratt Ah yes, it would not work in such case. You are correct in that situation. The OP, as it stands now, does not fully clarify the relationship between `g` and `G`. Indeed, purely by looking at the math programming model where `G` does not feature, one could interpret it as allowing the number of clusters to be endogenously determined.

Comment: Yes, the OP meant $g\in\{1,\dots,G\}$ instead of $g\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, and I corrected it.